# ¿Por qué mi código no genera la tabla bien?

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que trato de hacer con este código es pedir ingresar dos números entre 1 y 20, los cuales me servirán como límites para generar una tabla con el cuadrado y el cubo de los números dentro del rango. Por ejemplo, si los numeros ingresados son 4 y 15, el programa tiene que generar una tabla con 12 filas y tres columnas:

```
4---16---64
5---25---125
.
.
.
15---225---3375
```

Si en caso el primer número ingresado es mayor (por ejemplo 19 y 8 en ese orden), el programa debe ser capaz de reconocerme la tabla comenzando con el menor siempre. Y si en caso el número ingresado no esté entre 1 y 20, el programa debe continuar pidiendo el número hasta que el correcto se haya ingresado.

Éste es el código:

```js
//Registro los dos numeros y compruebo si es que estan entre 1 y 20
var number1 = window.prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 20:");

while (number1 <= 1 || number1 >= 20) {
  number1 = window.prompt("Input not in range. Enter a number between 1 and 20:");
}

var number2 = window.prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 20:");

while (number2 <= 1 || number2 >= 20) {
  number2 = window.prompt("Input not in range. Enter a number between 1 and 20:");
}


var initial_range = 0;
var final_range = 0;

//Comparo los numeros para saber cual es mayor y menor.
if (number1 > number2) {
  initial_range = number2;
  final_range = number1;
} else {
  initial_range = number1;
  final_range = number2;
}


//Genero la tabla con los cuadrados y cubos
document.writeln("<table border=1>");
for (var i = initial_range; i <= final_range; i++) {
  document.writeln("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + Math.pow(i, 2) + "</td><td>" + Math.pow(i, 3) + "</td></tr>");
}

document.writeln("</table>");
```

El problema que tengo con este código, es que solo me genera la tabla correctamente si es que ambos límites (es decir los 2 números ingresados) son de un solo dígito o dos dígitos. Por ejemplo 5 y 9, o 6 y 8, o también 15 y 19. Pero si es que es 5 y 18, o 3 y 19, solo me genera una fila con los resultados del número mayor.

¿Por qué puede ser eso y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es un problema al ser JavaScript un lenguaje de tipado débil y las variables que usas unas veces se consideran cadenas de texto y otras veces se consideran números enteros... y se comparan con respecto a ese tipo.

La causa es que la respuesta de un [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) es una cadena de texto. Entonces la primera comparación que se realiza (la de los límites) es sobre cadenas y no sobre números. Por ejemplo, como lo que estás comparando son cadenas, "18" es menor que "5" porque el primer carácter de "18" ("1") es menor que el primer carácter de "5" ("5").

Pero luego dentro del bucle que genera la tabla, la variable se considera un número entero (porque se va a comparar con la variable iteradora ques es numérica) y entonces se va desde el límite inferior (18, por el fallo anterior) incrementando mientras sea menor que el límite superior (5). Por lo que sólo se ejecuta una vez: la del valor superior, el comportamiento que estás viendo.

Una solución rápida que no requeriría muchos cambios de código sería hacer un [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) del `prompt` para que la cadena se convierta en un número entero y entonces los valores se comparen como enteros al principio, haciendo que los límites sean correctos:

```js
//Registro los dos numeros y compruebo si es que estan entre 1 y 20
var number1 = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 20:"));

while (number1 <= 1 || number1 >= 20) {
  number1 = parseInt(window.prompt("Input not in range. Enter a number between 1 and 20:"));
}

var number2 = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 20:"));

while (number2 <= 1 || number2 >= 20) {
  number2 = parseInt(window.prompt("Input not in range. Enter a number between 1 and 20:"));
}


var initial_range = 0;
var final_range = 0;

//Comparo los numeros para saber cual es mayor y menor.
if (number1 > number2) {
  initial_range = number2;
  final_range = number1;
} else {
  initial_range = number1;
  final_range = number2;
}


//Genero la tabla con los cuadrados y cubos
document.writeln("<table border=1>");
for (var i = initial_range; i <= final_range; i++) {
  document.writeln("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + Math.pow(i, 2) + "</td><td>" + Math.pow(i, 3) + "</td></tr>");
}

document.writeln("</table>");
```